# Is $E[g(x_i)g(x_j)]=E[g(x_i)]\,E[g(x_j)]$, for $x_i$ multinomial?

Tags: probability, variance, multinomial-coefficients

Consider the multinomial distribution (Wikipedia):

[image]

and let $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ a smooth function. I would like to know if one can show the identity

$$E[g(x_i)g(x_j)]=E[g(x_i)]\,E[g(x_j)],$$

for every $i\neq j$ fixed.

Comment: In a multinomial random vector, the components are dependent to each other. Some special function may exist such that $g(X_i), g(X_j)$ uncorrelated, but you should not expect that happen in general.

Comment: The mutual dependency is just because of the condition $n=\sum_i x_i$, isn't it?

Comment: Yes you may think in that way - they are negatively correlated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k=2$, and $n=1$. Let $g$ the identity map.

We have
$$X_1+X_2=1$$

then $$E[X_1X_2]=E[X_1(1-X_1)]=E[X_1]-E[X_1^2]=E[X_1]-E[X_1]=0$$

but $E[X_i] \ne 0$.